# Trying to locate email piping file

Tags: email, unix

About a year ago someone helped me to setup a file that would pipe email coming to a specific domain to a PHP script. I am on UNIX (CentOS) and know that the file should be in /etc/aliases

Have no idea what else to look for. I need to modify the file to add similar functionality for another domain.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What MTA (Mail Transport Authority) you are using: sendmail, postfix, etc?

Comment: I'm not really sure. In php I use mail(). How can I find out? I'll be happy to check.

Comment: Post the output of `lsof -i :25`

Comment: smtpd   21192 postfix    6u  IPv4   6478       TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)

Comment: That's great! Next time I'll know. So, where do I look for that piping file? Is there a way to search withing files for that domain name, perhaps?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4626/discussion-between-alexander-pogrebnyak-and-santa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For postfix:

**VERY IMPORTANT**: Save existing `/etc/postfix/master.cf` and `/etc/postfix/transport`.

Edit `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

Append these line

```
php-transport    unix  -       n       n       -        1      pipe
    flags=Rq user=phtran argv=/path/to/script.php ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Note: it's important to have white space before `flags`
For more parameters to `pipe` read this -> http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html

Create user `phtran` and assign it to be the owner of `/path/to/script.php`.  Make the script executable.

Add this line to `/etc/postfix/transport`

```
my.domain php-transport:
.my.domain php-transport:
```

Run

```
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
```

Here is the doc for tarnsport map: http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html

Restart postfix service.

Comment: @santa. Yes, I would most definitely do that.  I just do not know what you have already in place.

Comment: Wow, this is great! Before I go through with this, quick question: since I already have a pipe setup for another domain, shouldn't I try to modify that first? I searched for my php script and found that it is referenced from /etc/aliases:catchall-mails: "|/home/mypath/myscript.php" So, I guess, it is not based on a domain but just one script that can be modified to route messages based on domain name in the email addresses, right?

Comment: @santa. I don't know enough about your setup, but you may want to read aliases man page -> http://www.postfix.org/aliases.5.html